# Getting subquery error using string_agg function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2017 and I have a `SELECT` statement where I use `STRING_AGG` function in subquery like:

```
SELECT
    [p].[test],
    [p].[test], 
    ....
    (SELECT [Customers] 
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              STRING_AGG([C].[Name] , ', ') AS [Customers]
          FROM 
              [Project] AS [P]
          RIGHT JOIN 
              [ProjectCustomer] AS [PC] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [PC].[ProjectKey]
          INNER JOIN 
              [Customer] AS [C] ON [PC].[CustomerKey] = [C].[CustomerKey]
          GROUP BY
              [P].[Name]) AS [t])
FROM 
    ...
```

Problem is when I executed it, I get this exception:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

But if I run subquery as a individual select it runs and it only returns one string value. Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong there? Regards

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear?  Your subquery returns more than one row.  Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to run the inner query and see how many rows returned?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error message when using a GROUP BY and STRING_AGG in the same subquery. I added another subquery level to do the get mine to work. In your example, I would write this:

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(distinct_customers.[Name] , ', ') AS [Customers]
FROM
(
    SELECT
      [C].[Name]
    FROM 
      [Project] AS [P]
    RIGHT JOIN 
      [ProjectCustomer] AS [PC] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [PC].[ProjectKey]
    INNER JOIN 
      [Customer] AS [C] ON [PC].[CustomerKey] = [C].[CustomerKey]
    GROUP BY
      [P].[Name]) AS [t]
) AS distinct_customers
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure just doesn't make sense.  I am guessing you want:

```
select . . . ,
       (select string_agg(c.name, ', ')
        from ProjectCustomer pc join
             customers c
             on c.CustomerKey = pc.CustomerKey
        where p.ProjectKey = pc.ProjectKey
       ) as customer_names
from p;
```

Off-hand, I can't think of anything more useful with these tables.  But this is only a guess based on your query.